# Dialogflow v2 Java Client Library detectIntent with Spring Boot: No DesignTimeAgent found for project

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-api, dialogflow-es

While trying to `detectIntent` from text I have received a below exception (project-id was replaced). Cannot find anything in google related to `DesignTimeAgent` issue. Any help is appreciated.

Exception :

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: com.google.apps.framework.request.NotFoundException: No DesignTimeAgent found for project 'MY_PROJECT_ID'.
com.google.api.gax.rpc.NotFoundException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: com.google.apps.framework.request.NotFoundException: No DesignTimeAgent found for project 'MY_PROJECT_ID'.
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:45)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:95)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:61)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1015)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1137)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:957)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:748)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:493)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:468)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:684)
    ...
    Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112)
        at com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.SessionsClient.detectIntent(SessionsClient.java:245)
        at com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.SessionsClient.detectIntent(SessionsClient.java:184)
        at com.my.microservices.controllers.DialogFlowRestController.test(DialogFlowRestController.java:35)
        ...
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: com.google.apps.framework.request.NotFoundException: No DesignTimeAgent found for project 'MY_PROJECT_ID'.
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
    ... 23 more
```

Rest controller to trigger `detectIntent` test (as https://localhost:8080/api/test):

```java
package com.my.microservices.controllers;

import com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.UUID;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DialogFlowRestController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DialogFlowRestController.class);

    private String userText = "Weather forecast for today in Berlin";
    private final String LANG_CODE = "en-US";
    private final String PROJECT_ID = System.getenv().get("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT");
    private String sessionId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @GetMapping(value = "/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String test() throws Exception { 
        logger.info("test was called");

        try (SessionsClient sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create()) {
            SessionName session = SessionName.of(PROJECT_ID, sessionId);

            TextInput.Builder textInput = TextInput.newBuilder().setText(userText).setLanguageCode(LANG_CODE);

            QueryInput queryInput = QueryInput.newBuilder().setText(textInput).build();

            DetectIntentResponse response = sessionsClient.detectIntent(session, queryInput);
            return response.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Provided environment variables:

```sh
GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=MY_PROJECT_ID
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/me/.my/pk.json
```

Spring-Boot `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.my.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>dialog-flow-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dialog-flow-test</name>
    <description>Demo project with Dialog Flow</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dialogflow API Client Library for Java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-dialogflow</artifactId>
            <version>v2-rev81-1.25.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-dialogflow</artifactId>
            <version>0.103.0-alpha</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Also have tried with `curl`. Same error message:
```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-d @request.json \
https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/MY_PROJECT_ID/agent/sessions/123456789:detectIntent
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "com.google.apps.framework.request.NotFoundException: No DesignTimeAgent found for project 'MY_PROJECT_ID'.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have figured it out.

The above misleading error message was caused by the use of a wrong PROJECT_ID. My mistake was, that first I have created a new Project with a Service Account, gave to it dialogflow API rights and later I have tried to use its name and related PK JSON for my `detectIntent` calls. BUT it was not linked with Dialogflow Project ID.

So, to fix it I have started with a default Project ID, which was given to my new Dialogflow Agent and following instruction https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup I have created a new Project with a Service Account which fit my Dialogflow Agent.

Comment: thank you! your page helped me to get my connection working although intent is still giving me "default intent" only. not sure why it is not recognizing!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to move my Agent to Global serving from EU-W1